# Is page output cache stored in ASP.NET cache object?

Tags: asp.net, caching, asp.net-4.0

I need to enable caching in my asp.net application, but I do not want to use the webserver's memory for holding cache objects.  If I add the page directive for output caching will the page be stored in the asp.net cache object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behaviour is to store the content in memory in the same way as `HttpRuntime.Cache` (actually in an internal `HttpRuntime.CacheInternal` which behaves similarly to the publicly visible cache), but in ASP.NET 4.0 you can write your own provider to store the content however you wish.

This a nice introduction to implementing a provider and using it in your application: http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/aspnet-output-cache-provider

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you set as OutputCacheLocation

have a look at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation.aspx

Comment: OK..So now assume we are caching in server...then where can we see output cached objects during debugging?